# How to implement a custom protocol

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, protocols

In this part of my code I get a warning message saying it doesn't implement the custom protocol I made.

```
detailViewController.delegate = self;
```

How do I implement the protocol?

Then when I run the program it crashes saying

'-[DetailViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a1c450'

Answer (score 1):

Declare your class like this:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <MyProtocol> {
    // Class stuff
}
```

Comment: That removes the warning message, but it still crashes.

Comment: can you give more code please ? How did you declare your protocol ? Property, ...